# node.js & Express - cannot post form data

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, mongodb, form-submit

Been working on this for most of the night - and morning...
I have a large form which collects comments at various stages throughout a constitution document. At the end - the user submits the form and the form redirects to /constitution-comments (well it should!) which is a POST route. The final rendered page shows the comments (which will actually be saved to MongoDB but I am not that far along yet.

So the basics of the form are

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="constitutionForm" action="../routes/constitution-comments" method="post" >
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="GENERALComments">Your Comments</label>
                <div class="col-md-12">                     
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="GENERALComments" name="GENERALComments"></textarea>
                </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
<button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The route looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(server){

    server.post('/constitution', function(req, res){        
        res.render('./views/constitution/comments.ejs', {
            GENERALComments: req.body.GENERALComments,
        });
        // THIS IS NOT DISPLAYED
        console.log("\tIn /constitution POST");
    });
}
```

the console.log at the end of the route does not show up so it seems I am not getting here!

the view being rendered (or not) looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 center ">
        <h1 class="text-shad">
            Your Draft Constitution Comments
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <%= GENERALComments %>
    </div>
</div>
```

My routes and views are arranged like this:
[image: routes]

the full application as it stands can be found here:
[Full Application So Far][2]

For clarity: server is the express app.js

How do I get the form data to POST?

**UPDATE: COMPLETE CODE**

**server.js**

```
console.log("Adding Requires");
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var urlEncoded = require('urlencoded-request-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var override = require('method-override');
var rest = require('node-restful');

console.log("Creating Server Object");
var server = express();
server.locals.moment = require('moment');
server.set('ServerVersion', "5.0.1.7");

console.log("Server setting port");
var port = process.env.port || 1337;

console.log("Server setting \'Require Models\'");
var modelsPath="./models/"; 
fs.readdirSync(modelsPath).forEach(function(file) {
    var models=modelsPath+file;
    var bfile = path.basename(file,'.js');
    console.log("\tAdding model: " + bfile)
    require(models)(server);
});


console.log("Connecting to MongooseDB");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://mvm-mongodb.cloudapp.net/ccslabs-main");

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function callback () {
  console.log('Connected to MongoDB successfully');
});


server.use('/constitution', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('Request URL:', req.originalUrl);
  next();
}, function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Request Type:', req.method);
  next();
});

server.use('/constitution-comments', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('Request URL:', req.originalUrl);
  next();
}, function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Request Type:', req.method);
  console.log('Request Body:', req.body )
  console.log('Request Content-Type: ', req.get('Content-Type'));
  next();
});

server.use('/comments', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('Request URL:', req.originalUrl);
  next();
}, function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Request Type:', req.method);
  next();
});

server.disable('x-powered-by');

console.log("Server setting \'Server.Uses\'");
server.use(urlEncoded());
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
server.use(bodyParser.json());
server.use(override());

// this middleware will be executed for every request to the app
// server.use(function (req, res, next) {
//  console.log('Time: %s : Req: %s', server.locals.moment(),req.ip );
//  next();
// })

console.log("Server setting \'Require Routes\'");
var routePath="./routes/"; 
fs.readdirSync(routePath).forEach(function(file) {
    var route=routePath+file;
    var models=modelsPath+file;
    var bfile = path.basename(file,'.js');
    console.log("\tAdding route: " + bfile)
    require(route)(server);
});

console.log("\tAdding Static Files\' routes");
server.use(express.static(__dirname + "/content"));

console.log("Server creating \'Server.Sets\'");
server.set('view engine', 'ejs');
server.set('views', __dirname);
server.set('Content-Type','application:json')
// Why does the version not display??
server.set('ver',"0.0.2.8")
console.log("Server Version: "+ server.ver);

server.listen(port);
console.log("Server listening on port " + port);
```

The full code can be found here: [Github link (temporary)](https://github.com/ccslabs/Hanas)

Comment: Can you show the code where you are using/loading the `/constitution` POST route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

The resolution to the above problem was the following.

1) I changed the route back to "/post-put" in the form Action and in the Route file. 2) I added enctype="multipart/form-data" to the form.

So the form now looks like

```
<form method="post" action="/post-put" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <fieldset>

        <!-- Form Name -->
        <legend>Which Test Type</legend>

        <!-- Multiple Radios (inline) -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="TestType">Please test our</label>
            <div class="col-md-4"> 
                <label class="radio-inline" for="TestType-0">
                    <input type="radio" name="TestType" id="TestType-0" value="SoftwareTest" checked="checked">
                    Software
                </label> 
                <label class="radio-inline" for="TestType-1">
                    <input type="radio" name="TestType" id="TestType-1" value="HardwareTest">
                    Hardware
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <input type='submit' class="btn btn-default" id='submit' value='Submit your Test'/>
</form>
```

**ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION**

Keep the form enctype as `enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` In App.js (my server.js) Remove `app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded());` Change `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));` to `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());`

Now the POST method of the form works! Thanks to those who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `action` on your `<form>` isn't correct. It should be (assuming `server` is your Express `app` and not a mounted router): `action="/constitution"`

Comment: That still does not work. Would that not have it routed to consitution.js ? There is only a GET in that - the POST is in comments.js

Comment: It doesn't matter what files you have your routes in. You added a `/constitution` POST route somewhere and that's where you're expecting the form to go to, assuming like I said that `server` is not a mounted router.

Comment: Not sure if it is a mounted router or not - I think it may be :P
I have edited the Question and added the full source code Repo link to Github